# C# complex class constructors

Tags: c#, class, properties, class-constructors

I have the following system: a "mother" class called `DataClass`, has properties and two of them are classes, `PartClass` and `MemberClass`. In particular, `MemberClass` has properties and one of them is a class, `SideClass` - with its own properties.

Here is the code sample:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class DataClass
    {
        public int num { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public PartClass part { get; set; }
        public MemberClass member { get; set; }

        public DataClass()
        {
            PartClass part = new PartClass();
            MemberClass member = new MemberClass();
        }
    }

    public class PartClass
    {
        public int seriesNum { get; set; }
        public string seriesCode { get; set; }

        public PartClass() { }
    }

    public class MemberClass
    {
        public int versionNum { get; set; }
        public SideClass side { get; set; }

        public MemberClass()
        {
            SideClass side = new SideClass();
        }
    }

    public class SideClass
    {
        public string firstDetail { get; set; }
        public string secondDetail { get; set; }
        public bool include { get; set; }

        public SideClass() { }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to initialize the `DataClass` and assign values to all properties, and this doesn't work.
So, the `DataClass` "owns" the `PartClass` and the `MemberClass` and the `MemberClass` itself "sees" the `SideClass` which is the bottom class and sort of independent of all.
Here the rest of code:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    DataClass myData = new DataClass()
    {
        num = 13,
        code = "message",
        //from here downwards nothing works; error..
        part.seriesNum = 1,
        part.seriesCode = 7,
        member.versionNum = 9,
        member.side.firstDetail = "pass",
        member.side.secondDetail = "checked",
        member.side.include = true;
    }
}
```

}

I thought that by installing constructors and properties the `DataClass` instantiation would not have problems, but actually the `DataClass` does not see any non-trivial properties (properties referring to classes).
Could someone help me please? Thank you..

Comment: I thought I am initializing the "part" and "member" by `PartClass part = new PartClass();` and `MemberClass member = new MemberClass();` inside DataClass. What am I missing?..

Comment: No, you didn't initialize your properties, you defined new variables, and initialized them. It's `part = new ..`, not `PartClass part = new ..`, if you want it explicit, write `this.part= new ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following :

```cs
DataClass myData = new DataClass()
{
    num = 13,
    code = "message",
    part = new PartClass()
    {
        seriesNum = 1,
        //here down nothing works; error
        seriesCode = "abc"
    },
    member = new MemberClass()
    {
        versionNum = 9,
        side = new Side()
        {
            firstDetail = "pass",
            secondDetail = "checked",
            include = true
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you very much - worked. Just a question, since I add as per your code the "part = new PartClass()" etc, why do I need the constructors in the first place? I mean, I could do the exact code by just having the classes without any link themeselves? Thank you indeed for your time and effort, appreciate..

Comment: Every class needs a constructor unless it is static or virtual.

Comment: @jdweng I agree, I asked because I have put all the constructors in the classes above. And a question, how to I access the class, I tried `Console.WriteLine(myData.member.side.secondDetail);` and cannot parse it (though your code compiles, minor typos fixed). Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick Nobody can put a constructor from one class in another class, what you mean is instance-creation. I gave you the hint below your question. You are not accessing your properties at all in the constructor of the container.

Comment: Oops accidentally deleted my comment... @jdweng sorry, you were right, you definitely need the constructors as you have them

Comment: Do you have a side class? You didn't post one.  Make sure the property is public.

Comment: @Michael No, the class needs the constructor, but you don't need to define it. You can delete all the constructors above, it wouldn't change anything. Compiler would generate them for you and that's enough.

Comment: @jdwend yes, it is in the code as `public class SideClass` in first box, and is having an (empty) constructor inside...

Comment: @Holger hi, thank you for the comment. Actually, I followed the 'official' documentation - reason I did it is that this was my was to 'link' the classes to the DataClass. I am trying to have the DataClass with everything inside, so that, for example, I can do `public DataClass()` (which now fails by the way, even though I did the code as @jdweng proposed.. I saw your comment, how should I make it so that `public DataClass()` succeeds?

Comment: @Holger no, I had originally commented that he didn't need the part/side/member  constructor calls in the object initialization. The scary thing is not only did it compile, but my linter recommended it.

Comment: @Michael It's local variables, nothing related to members ! That's the thing.

Comment: @Holger, thank you, you are right, I deleted all the in-the-class constructors and the `Console.WriteLine(myData.member.side.secondDetail);` worked (gave result "checked"). Thank you very much.. I wonder why didn't threw error, but anyhow. So actually I never have to do this, the constructors, just initialize the objects when I populate the DataClass and put the constructors there, as in `DataClass myData = new DataClass() { ... part = new PartClass() { ... }, member = new MemberClass() { ...side = new SideClass() { ... }}};` etc. ok...

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure you understood your little mistake. You made everything right, except you wrote something like `int x = 5` where your were supposed to put `x = 5`. You see the difference ? One contains the datatype and creates a new variable.
And the other one, accesses a variable, defined somewhere else. If you just copy&paste working solutions, you never learn what was wrong.

Comment: @Holger OMG I see now what you mean. Kindly point me to line of code where it should have done differently if you don't mind. And thank you very much for time and effort!

Answer (score 2):

To not have to create the instance of Member Class and Part Class manually every time, you can create the instances using get and set methods.

```
public class DataClass
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }

    private PartClass _part;
    public PartClass part { get { if (_part == null) _part = new PartClass(); return _part; } set { _part = value; } }


    private MemberClass _member;
    public MemberClass member { get { if (_member == null) _member = new MemberClass(); return _member; } set { _member = value; } }

}
```

Comment: Today also just `{get => _part ?? (_part = new PartClass()); }`

Answer (score 0):

you should create an instance of DataClass then initialize fields

```
DataClass myData = new DataClass();

myData.num = 13,
myData.code = "message",
myData.part.seriesNum = 1,
myData.part.seriesCode = 7,
myData.member.versionNum = 9,
myData.member.side.firstDetail = "pass",
myData.member.side.secondDetail = "checked",
myData.member.side.include = true;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked as a charm. As a last favor, do you have any advices on the above implementation? have you spotted something trivial that I could have done better? your opinion matters. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: you should make the fields as privates and use set method to change value

Comment: There is still no `myData.part = new PartClass()`, it's impossible this works.

Comment: @Nick, change the constructor like this public DataClass()
        {
            part = new PartClass();
            member = new MemberClass();
        }

Comment: @Renato Coqueiro - impressive, however, I don't see the SideClass which is inside the MemberClass.. would you like to edit and let me get your approach?

Comment: @Marwen jaffel Sorry, I didn't understand, you mean in DataClass() as is posted originally in the question, to add the parts you mention and just get rid of the constructor? I will try now..

Comment: @Nick in the definition of DataClass constructor change it like this DataClass() { part = new PartClass(); member = new MemberClass(); }

Comment: @Marwen Jaffel Thank you I did (was surprised that it worked without the "public" keyword, and I also corrected the part and member inside the constructor..